# My attempt at proving that $A - (B -A) = A$, where $A$ and $B$ are sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

So, once again, I'm back with a proof that I've been trying to write up. The problem is as follows:

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. Then, $A-(B-A) = A$, where $A-B$ denotes the relative complement of $B$ in $A$.

---

***Proof:***

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. We also introduce the set $U$ such that $A \subset U$ and $B \subset U$. Let $x$ be an object in $U$. Then:

$x \in A - (B - A) \iff (x \in A) \land \lnot{(x \in B-A)}$

$x \in A - (B - A) \iff (x \in A) \land \lnot{[(x \in B) \land \lnot{(x \in A)}]}$

$x \in A - (B - A) \iff (x \in A) \land [\lnot{(x \in B)} \lor (x \in A)]$

$x \in A - (B - A) \iff  [(x \in A) \land \lnot{(x \in B)}] \lor (x \in A)$

$x \in A -(B - A) \iff x \in A$

Now, the claim that I'm making is that there is an equivalence between the last line and the 2nd last line. To prove this, suppose there wasn't. Hence, one can be false and the other can be true.

Let $x \in A$ be false and that massive proposition in the 2nd last line (we'll just call it P) be true. Then, $(x \in A) \land \lnot{(x \in B)}$ must be true. However, that's not possible as that would have to mean that $x \in A$ is true. That's a contradiction, so $x \in A$ cannot be false and P cannot be true.

Let $x \in A$ be true and P be false. However, that's a problem because $x \in A$ being true is enough to allow for P to be true, by the definition of the disjunction. Hence, this is a contradiction so $x \in A$ cannot be false and P cannot be true.

Thus, they both have to be true at the same time or they both have to be false. That means that they are equivalent and by the Axiom of Extension, that last line proves that $A - (B - A) = A$ holds.

---

Yea, I'd liked to know if I've messed up anywhere in my approach. If you can provide a shorter proof, that would be great but please also let me know if my argument above makes sense.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Btw., the deduction made (fortunately) also holds when $x\notin U$.

Comment: Hmm yea i should prove that separately. U was a set that I introduced, since I was considering the possibility of the objects not belonging in both A and B.

Comment: But my deduction, as I've stated above, is clear and correct right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your proof is correct, albeit a bit overcomplicated.

*My suggestion of proof*:
\begin{eqnarray*}
x \in (A - (B - A)) &\implies& (x \in A) \land (x \notin (B -A)) \\
&\implies& x \in A. 
\end{eqnarray*}
Since every element in the first set must exist in the second set, we can conclude that $(A - (B - A)) \subseteq A$. On the other hand, if $x \in A$, then $x$ cannot be an element in any set subtracted with $A$. In other words, $x \notin (B - A)$. We therefore have that
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
x \in A &\implies& (x \in A) \land (x \notin (B - A)) \\
&\implies& x \in (A - (B - A)).
\end{eqnarray}
$$
By the same argument as earlier, we have that $A \subseteq (A - (B - A))$. Since we now have two sets that are subsets of each other, they have to be equal, i.e. $A = (A - (B - A))$.

Comment: Ah thank you! That given proof is so short tbh.

Comment: At the moment, I'm trying to practise using the laws of logic that I learned from the previous chapter of the book that I'm using. So, I'm avoiding the use of text and simply relying on the use of formal statements. I feel like that's just causing me issues though, cos my proofs tend to become dramatically longer.